# Text to Speech in a jScript Program not running in Browser

Tags: text-to-speech, jscript

I am trying to add text to speech (TTS) to a standalone JScript program that is not running in a browser.  The SW manufacturer that has enabled the users to write their own JScript programs states that "JScript Module is designed to work with Microsoft jscript.dll".

I have tried to link to the external TTS programs that offer Windows command line such as dSpeech, however it looks like JScript does not allow for an external app to be called.

I also tried using SpeechSynthesisUtterance and that did not work either.

My program will create a text string that I want the user to be able to hear when a specific event occurs.  The text string changes for each event.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rosetta Code is a good place to start: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#Batch_File

```js
var objVoice = new ActiveXObject("SAPI.SpVoice");
objVoice.speak("Hello World");
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error        ERROR    Line 10: error #0x0: "" :  / Controller::scriptError() {src\Controller.cpp:104}